# Maven: Programming to Interface Projects

Tags: java, maven, projects-and-solutions

I am wondering If it is possible to implement an interface project in maven as below.

Project-A and Project-B have same classes implements interfaces in Project-C.
Project-Z uses only Project-I(POM) which includes Project A,B,C as module.

I want to use profile mechanism so that either Project-A or Project-B's implementation will be used by Project-Z.

Please give me a simple example if you think it is possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java [SPI](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/extensible/index.html) (Service Provider Interface) by which the two implementing jars declare the same service in the manifest. Using apps can do a lookup, iterate over them and pick one. *(I did not find a simple example on the spot.)*

Comment: Yes, but i want Project-I(POM) to choose the module not other apps.

Comment: Then use the **delegate/factory** pattern, implement the interface in a third class which delegates to one of the two direct implementations. And only provide that delegating class.

Comment: I don't think I can apply delegate pattern for each project. There shall be solution at project level via profiles. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way that comes to mind if you really want to do it with a maven profile, you could set a property with the classname in the profile. Then instantiate the class in this property at runtime.

```
<profile>
    <id>a</id> 
    <properties> 
         <myproject.componentX.implementation.class>com.foo.bar.BazA</myproject.componentX.implementation.class>
```

seems perhaps strange why you'd want to do it at build time in the root pom .... maybe you plan on not changing it often. there are better ways, depending on what you plan to do.

could you explain in what cases you want to change it and why and how often?